# Cannot access eclipse orion server from local machine using local IP

Tags: linux, centos, jetty, eclipse-orion

I have been given a centos server to lauch eclipse orion code editor. I installed eclipse orion as per the instruction on https://wiki.eclipse.org/Orion/How_Tos/Install_Orion_on_Localhost (steps for linux using jetty server). It works fine on centos browser. The centos os is running on 198.168.1.226. So that I can access the following urls on web browser of centos.

1. 198.168.1.226:8080
2. localhost:8080
3. 127.0.0.1:8080
4. 0.0.0.0:8080

But when I tried to access the 198.168.1.226:8080 from other local machines on local network, that is not accessible. I searched the StackOverflow Questions like [how to make jetty server accessible from LAN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808075/how-to-make-jetty-server-accessible-from-lan?s=1|3.5274) and [Unable to access jetty server with local IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270171/unable-to-access-jetty-server-with-local-ip-address?s=2|0.9820) but both are useless for me. How can I fix this situation? Can I fix it editing the code on orion.ini file or need to deal with configuration file or something else?

I have also tried the orion for windows computer but it worked itself for accessing the orion system for any other computer in local network. But I am surprised to face it on centos using the jetty server for setting up eclipse-orion system .

Comment: Sounds like either a firewall and/or iptables configuration issue preventing access to that Jetty server instance from outside of your machine.

Comment: How can I just track where the issue is a  firewall and/or iptables configuration issue?

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all check that have you allowed specific port (8080) from eclispse.
2. add rule with that port no. in centos iptables as below:-

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 (adjust according your port no.) -j ACCEPT