# How to access central server/database from other computer or mobile all in a router

Tags: java, mysql, networking, xampp

I have a web application in java, works fine in localhost:8080 with embedded jetty server powered by web-swing. However my computer is in a home-group network. There are several computer in same home-group. All computer connected with router switch.

```
my router IP:   192.168.0.1
my computer(A) IP: 192.168.0.101
Another computer(B) IP: 192.168.0.102
```

However i cannot establish a connection from computer B browser....

192.168.0.101:8080/myapp

> ```
> But in my computer(A) :  localhost:8080/myapp works fine 
> but 192.168.0.101:8080/myapp also not work.
> ```

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make jetty server accessible from LAN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808075/how-to-make-jetty-server-accessible-from-lan)

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not the problem of router. `8080` suggests that you are deploying `Java` in debug mode. Debug servers aren't capable of serving production ready content and this is why it's default configuration does not allow to connect from addresses different than `localhost`. You should change your's server configuration.

Also, please take a look at your's firewall configuration, as it also can block incoming connections by default.