# How to Access Jenkins Remotely from Maven Run

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Since manually executing steps of my plugin with demo projects takes some time, I'd like to execute it on a separate server using `mvn hpi:run`. To access Jenkins on my desktop, I'd like to tunnnel e.g. using `ssh server -L 8080:server`. Unfortunately, I cannot access the server with tunnelling and even on the server itself, `curl localhost:8080` works and `curl server:8080` does not work (and `ssh server` works, so it is not a connection problem).

Since ufw is disabled, I assume that the Jenkins which is run by maven usually only listens to `127.0.0.1`. To change this, according to https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS//Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins, either setting `--httpListenAddress=0.0.0.0` or setting `$HTTP_HOST` should be possible (https://serverfault.com/questions/408657/how-to-access-jenkins-remotely-on-ubuntu-12-04-server).

Unfortunately, both versions

```
mvn clean hpi:run -DhttpListenAddress=0.0.0.0
export HTTP_HOST=0.0.0.0 && mvn clean hpi:run
```

did not succeed. Additionally, I guessed `-Djetty.host=0.0.0.0` could work ([how to make jetty server accessible from LAN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808075/how-to-make-jetty-server-accessible-from-lan)) since the port of Jenkins can be set using `-Djetty.port`, but it also did not work:

```
mvn clean hpi:run -Djetty.host=0.0.0.0
```

Is there any option to make a Jenkins plugin directly remote accessible when using `hpi:run`, or is it necessary to deploy it to a local Jenkins server everytime?

Comment: Please allow me to question this. Why not just run the test in a Jenkins build instead of triggering Jenkins from Maven?

Comment: My goal is to apply my plugin to demo projects, which I can do either in a regular Jenkins instance of or in a Jenkins instance started by `mvn hpi:run`. It is not about just running a unit test, which could be done in a Jenkins build. Thanks for the hint, I changed the beginning to make this clearer.

Comment: What would be best is mock and test your plugin. But sometimes is not possible, so as you said,  a Jenkins instance is required to a real test of plugin. #1 Are you open to another workaround without jenkins? #2 According to the [docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/tutorial/run/) hpi:run starts a new jenkins instance. What you want is connect your `mvn hpi:run` to an already jenkins instance? #3 What is your o.s ?

Comment: #1 I would be open to any workaround easier then what I am currently doing (Ctrl + C for jenkins, `mvn clean package && cp target/project-VERSION.hpi ~/.jenkins/plugins` and `java -jar jenkins.war`). #2 That would be ok, but I would prefer if `hpi:run` would open a new instance and make it publicly accessible. Probably best solution would be to search in https://github.com/jenkinsci/maven-plugin why the `httpListenAddress` is not passed. #3 I am running on Ubuntu (currently 18.04 and 20.04).

Answer (score 2):

Following worked for me:

```
mvn -Dhost=0.0.0.0 hpi:run
```